# How to build a Shape with screw threads?

Tags: opencascade

I wang to make a Shape with screw threads by Opencascade,just like the attached file shows.
Would you please give me a C++ example code?
I followed the bottle example. But that is not clear enough.

I followed the bottle example. But that is not clear enough.